# Class defined errors

Tags: c#, validation, error-handling

I would like to keep my errors separate as when defined their is a lot of detail, this is an error model:

```
public interface IErrorResult : IResult
{
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

An example of this being used:

```
public static class CheckoutError
{
    public static ErrorResult Purchased = new ErrorResult
    {
        Code = CheckoutErrors.AlreadyPurchased,
        Message = "License already bought.",
        Description = "A license for this account already exists."
    };

    public static ErrorResult Expired = new ErrorResult
    {
        Code = CheckoutErrors.Expired,
        Message = "Checkout Expired.",
        Description = "The checkout session expired, please try again."
    };

    public static ErrorResult NotFound = new ErrorResult
    {
        Code = CheckoutErrors.NotFound,
        Message = "Checkout not found.",
        Description = "This checkout session doesn't exist."
    };
}
```

The reason why I have these defined separately is so they can be reused and it makes it a lot easier to modify them when necessary.

These errors are used within a validator which is called before the business logic is called like so:

```
public class CheckoutValidator : ICheckoutValidator
{
    private readonly ICheckoutSessionRepository _checkoutSessionRepository;
    private readonly ILicenseValidator _licenseValidator;

    public CheckoutValidator(ICheckoutSessionRepository checkoutSessionRepository)
    {
        _checkoutSessionRepository = checkoutSessionRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IResult> ValidateSession(string userId)
    {
        var checkout = await _checkoutSessionRepository.GetBySession(userId);
        if (checkout == default(CheckoutSession) || checkout.User.AspNetUserId != userId)
        {
            var error = CheckoutError.NotFound;
            error.Status = ResultStatusEnum.NotFound;
            return error;
        }

        if (DateTime.Now > checkout.Expires)
        {
            var error = CheckoutError.Expired;
            error.Status = ResultStatusEnum.Invalid;
            return error;
        }

        return new Result
        {
            Status = ResultStatusEnum.Valid
        };
    }
}
```

I was wondering, is this sort of design something that is commonly used? I feel it could be made simpler and I've over complicated things but I'm struggling to see where and what bits could be changed and improved

Comment: Care with `error.Status = ResultStatusEnum.NotFound;` because this modify the `CheckoutError.NotFound` instance.

Comment: @Vernou It is fine to modify the `Status` property as in different situations the result status could vary. This is then used in the controller to understand what to send back to the user i.e `NotFound()` or `BadRequest()`

Comment: The problem is the same instance is reused. In parallel context (like API), this can produce errors very hard to debug. If a request produce `NotFound` and other produce `BadRequest` are executed at the same time, the result isn't predictable.

Comment: @Vernou I don't think I understand, can you provide an example?

Comment: @Vernou Is it because it is a static class? Should I change this?

Comment: Request 1 begin. Request 1 set status to NoFound. Request 2 begin. Request 2 set status to BadRequest. Request 1 return status (BadRequest). Request 2 return status (BadRequest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few error models I have seen and used

Alternatives that simply succeed/Fail

1. `bool Try*(out T result)` - pattern
2. Return null
3. Return a [Maybe Monad](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1510/maybe-monad-csharp)

Alternatives that provide additional information about the failure

1. Throw an exception
2. Return a [result-object](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults)

There are various disadvantages/advantages with each option. With regard to [exception vs result objects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/405038/result-object-vs-throwing-exceptions), One point of view is that exceptions should be used for 'exceptional', i.e. unexpected and rare errors, while result objects should be used for common and/or expected errors. *Out of memory* could be an example of the former, while an invalid user could be an example of an expected error.

With regards to your specific implementation there are a few issues:

1. Your result object is not generic, so what will you do if you need to return some arbitrary object? It seems like the caller would have to do some casting to get anything useful out of the returned object, and that often leads to messy code. I would suggest making the result object generic, look at [this implementation](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults) for inspiration
2. You have Errors are static (i.e. global) objects, but have public setters. This is a big no-no that can very easily result in strange behaviors. Consider for example if the error object are accessed from multiple threads (the properties could change at any time), or if you forget to set one of the properties (it would keep the last value) . Either make the objects immutable, or change them to methods that return new objects.